# How to terminate every process with the current process name except for the current process

Tags: c#, process, kill-process

Im trying to terminate every process with the same name as my process without killing my process. 
This might be a bit confusing, maybe this code will help you understand what i meant:

```
private static void KillExistingProcesses()
    {
        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        foreach (var pro in p)
        {
            if (...) // if pro != Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            pro.Kill();
        }
    }
```

I tried doing this:

```
            if (!pro.Equals(Process.GetCurrentProcess()) 
            && pro != Process.GetCurrentProcess())
```

But i still end up terminating my own process. 
Can you guys help me with this? I just need to terminate every process with the same name of my process excpet for the current process.

 Thank you :)

Comment: I would think you want the ones where `Process.ProcessName` are equal and `Process.Id` is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing `Process` objects which have no meaningful equality relation defined.

Compare the process IDs.

Comment: Yea i figured that, thanks for the help ill try doing what you said!
Edit: It works, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can estimate your own Process-ID and then, in the loop, compare it to element:

```
    private static void KillExistingProcesses()
    {
        Process myProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        ;
        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        foreach (var pro in p)
        {
            if (pro.Id != myProc.Id)
            {
                pro.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yea thanks, @usr said the same thing and it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Linq to filter out the processes with the same `Id`

```
Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName)
                       .Where(p => p.Id != current.Id);
foreach(var process in processes)
{
    process.Kill(); 
}
```